# Normalize strings that represent (combinatorical) necklaces

Tags: python, combinatorics, string-comparison, string-matching

I'm trying to match ["necklaces"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29) of symbols in Python by looking up their linear representations, for which I use normal strings. For example, the strings `"AABC"`, `"ABCA"`, `"BCAA"`, `"CAAB"` all represent the same necklace (pictured).

[image: symbol loop "AABC"]

In order to get an overview, I store only *one* of the equivalent strings of a given necklace as a "representative". As to check if I've stored a candidate necklace, I need a function to normalize any given string representation. As a kind of pseudo code, I wrote a function in Python:

```
import collections

def normalized(s):
    q = collections.deque(s)
    l = list()
    l.append(''.join(q))
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        q.rotate(1)
        l.append(''.join(q))
    l.sort()
    return l[0]
```

For all the string representations in the above example necklace, this function returns `"AABC"`, which comes first alphabetically.

Since I'm relatively new to Python, I wonder - if I'd start implementing an application in Python - would this function be already "good enough" for production code? In other words: Would an experienced Python programmer use this function, or are there obvious flaws?

Comment: `the patterns [abc] [bca] [cab] should all being considered identical` Okay, but your program returns a String... Why is that?

Comment: i didnt get what you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, this was indeed a little confusing. I hope, it's better now.

Comment: @downvoter: what exactly is wrong with the question? What should be improved?

Comment: I tried make the question as clear as needed to reopen it.

Comment: *"How would a python programmer solve this problem?"* - given that you've written a Python program to solve the problem, haven't you answered your own question? If you want a review of your code, consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's about efficiency - not code review in general. But maybe you are right. It's not easy to decide where to ask questions with a tendency to overlap; an SO is of course the most responsive site compared to [programmers](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @Wolf Performance improvement related questions are normally on-topic at Code Review.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I see. I'm currently not very active there, but re-posting seems not an option now. ...and the reason for closing was not that the question was off-topic. Well, maybe next it will be ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you first need to construct all circular permutations of the input sequence and then determine the (lexicographically) smallest element. That is the root of your symbol loop.
Try this:

```
def normalized(s):
    L = [s[i:] + s[:i] for i in range(len(s))]
    return sorted(L)[0]
```

This code works only with strings, no conversions between queue and string as in your code. A quick timing test shows this code to run in 30-50% of the time.
It would be interesting to know the length of `s` in your application. As all permutations have to be stored temporarily len(s)^2 bytes are needed for the temp list `L`. Hopefully this is not a constraint in your case.

**Edit:**
Today I stumbled upon the observation that if you concatenate the original string to itself it will contain all rotations as substrings. So the code will be:

```
def normalized4(s):
    ss = s + s      # contains all rotations of s as substrings
    n = len(s)
    return min((ss[i:i+n] for i in range(n)))
```

This will indeed run faster as there is only one concatination left plus n slicings. Using stringlengths of 10 to 10**5 the runtime is between 55% and 66% on my machine, compared to the min() version with a generator.

Please note that you trade off speed for memory consumption (2x) which doesn't matter here but might do in a different setting.

Comment: Couldn't this be made even more efficient by using `min` on a generator expression instead of sorting a list?

Comment: `min()` on a generator circumvents the memory issue which is apparent for stringlengths > 1000. Thanks to Arpegius for this pythonic improvement!

Comment: @user1016274 yes, that's exactly what I was trying to ask ;-) The length will be below 10 I think. I wish to demonstrate something about permutations.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `min` rather then sorting:

```
def normalized2(s):
    return min(( s[i:] + s[:i] for i in range(len(s)) ))
```

But still it needs to copy string `len(s)` times. Faster way is to filter starting indexes of smallest char, until you get only one. Effectively search for smallest loop:

```
def normalized3(s):
    ssize=len(s)
    minchar= min(s)
    minindexes= [ i for i in range(ssize) if minchar == s[i] ]
    for offset in range(1,ssize):
        if len( minindexes ) == 1 :
            break
        minchar= min( s[(i+offset)%ssize] for i in minindexes )
        minindexes= [i for i in minindexes if minchar == s[(i+offset)%ssize]]
    return s[minindexes[0]:] + s[:minindexes[0]]
```

For long string this is much faster:

```
In [143]: loop = [ random.choice("abcd") for i in range(100) ]
In [144]: timeit normalized(loop)
1000 loops, best of 3: 237 µs per loop
In [145]: timeit normalized2(loop)
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.3 µs per loop
In [146]: timeit normalized3(loop)
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.9 µs per loop
```

But if we have much of repetition, this method is not eficient:

```
In [147]: loop = "abcd" * 25
In [148]: timeit normalized(loop)
1000 loops, best of 3: 245 µs per loop
In [149]: timeit normalized2(loop)
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.8 µs per loop
In [150]: timeit normalized3(loop)
1000 loops, best of 3: 612 µs per loop
```

We can also scan forward the string, but I doubt it could be any faster, without some fancy algorithm.

Comment: yes, I also thought of filtering along with generating the permutations. I expect that for long loops with a rich alphabet this will be the only option.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
patterns = ['abc', 'bca', 'cab']
normalized = lambda p: ''.join(sorted(p))
normalized_patterns = set(normalized(p) for p in patterns)
```

Example output:

```
In [1]: normalized = lambda p: ''.join(sorted(p))

In [2]: normalized('abba')
Out[2]: 'aabb'

In [3]: normalized('CBAE')
Out[3]: 'ABCE'
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough, would you please have a look again?

Comment: That's effectively what I'm doing. I'll try to clarify :)

Comment: Again, I'm very sorry for editing. I hope the problem is clear now?

Comment: @Wolf: can you give me some example input/output? I believe my code solves your problem already, if it doesn't I'd like to know :)

Comment: two more samples: norm("abba") ==> "aabb", norm("CBAE") ==> "AECB"

Comment: It actually does that right now:
`In [1]: normalized = lambda p: ''.join(sorted(p))

In [2]: normalized('abba')
Out[2]: 'aabb'

In [3]: normalized('CBAE')
Out[3]: 'ABCE'`

Comment: That's the problem with your approach. Try to imagine the a loop in the pattern CBAE: C -> B -> A -> E -> C and so on. Don't break neighbourhood relations.

Comment: In that case my answer is indeed useless, I'll leave it for reference but it won't work for your specific case :)